# QT serial port static building with qt app to deploy it for all linux systems

Tags: qt, qtserialport

I need to build my QT app which uses serialport shared library and due to this when i release this app for other systems, it says:

```
./qtnym: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5SerialPort.so.5: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.
```

After that i need to manually install qt5 required dependencies on the target device to get it working.
I am using qt-version 5.9.5
I have followed this:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/14781/qt-static-and-3rd-party-static-library
but the other method of including *.pri is not explained and this flag method also didn't work.

```
CONFIG += static
```

Also tried building the serialport source project, after done building, i am not getting a way to link it with my project.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [appimage](https://appimage.org/) to bundle your application and make usable on any other device.

Comment: Thanks, I got across qtlinuxdeploy tool which uses appimage, My work is done